# Kendo Grid does not recognize Grid event builder function "FilterMenuInit"

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to make some modifications in kendo grid filter.I will customize filter using a function which will be called in Grid event builder :FilterMenuInit

But code is showing that this is not a function.

Is there any version problem ?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Fitsom.Models.RegisteredUsersModel>()
                          .Name("UsersGrid")
                          .Events(events => 
                                    **events.FilterMenuInit("gridFilterMenuInit"))** ----Here is the error
                          .Columns(columns =>
                          {
```

Please suggest.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are using a version which doesn't yet support the FilterMenuInit event. Try downloading a more recent version.